# How to authenticate Token using external Auth API in Lumen

Tags: php, microservices, lumen

I'm developing a microservice in Lumen. The microservice will use Auth Microservice to generate `API Key` or `ClientID/Secret(JWT TOKEN)`.

Whenever a customer with valid `Token` or `API Key` sends API call, I want to verify it using Auth Microservice.

For the verification purpose, I created

```
/api/oauth/verify - with encrypted TOKEN in header in Auth Microservice
```

This endpoint will return `id` of user on verification.

Here is the code I did on middleware of the Microservice to send TOKEN for verification

```
        $newEncrypter = new \Illuminate\Encryption\Encrypter( config('app.key'), Config::get( 'app.cipher' ) );
        $encryptedBearerToken = $newEncrypter->encrypt( $request->bearerToken() );
        //dd($bearerToken);
        $client = new Client(
            [
                'headers' => [
                    'Accept' => 'application/json',
                    'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $request->bearerToken()
                ],
                'verify' => false
            ]);
        $response = $client->post($url, ['json' => ['token' => $encryptedBearerToken]])->getBody()->getContents();
        $response = json_decode($response);
        $request->user = $response;
```

Code on middleware of Auth Microservice

```
    $bearerToken = $request->bearerToken();
    $encryptedToken = $request->token;
    if(!empty($encryptedToken))
    {
        $newEncrypter = new \Illuminate\Encryption\Encrypter( config('app.message_key'), Config::get( 'app.cipher' ) );
        $decryptedBearerToken = $newEncrypter->decrypt( $encryptedToken );

        if($bearerToken !== $decryptedBearerToken)
        {
            return $this->invalidToken();
        }
    }

    $validateApi = $this->authenticate(['api']);
    if(!$validateApi)
    {
        if(empty($bearerToken))
        {
            return $this->invalidToken();
        }
        $user = User::where('api_key', $bearerToken)->first();

        if(empty($user))
        {
            return $this->invalidToken();
        }
        \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::setUser($user);
    }
```

Some questions regarding above code implementation

- Is the approach for sending encrypted Token to external API valid?
- Is it the best way to authenticate TOKEN or API Key?

Problems:

- The Curl request on middleware to Auth Microservice is quite time consuming and on load test causing `502 Gateway timeout`

How can I authenticate TOKEN in better way and optimize the authentication

> [NOTE: The implementation is working fine when doing single Request
>   via POSTMAN]